# Event loop vs Callback function in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, event-loop

What is the difference between Event Loop and Callback function in node.js?

Answer (score 2):

Event Loop is in the underlying system that execute your program. Every time your code needs to access an external resource (for example a XHR call to an api) you usually do something like that:

```
callToTheApi('/api/some/url', function(response) { ... the callback code ...}
```

The runtime execute the call and pass the callback function (second parameter of the callToTheApi function) to the Event Queue. This means '*Execute the call to the api and when the api has done please tell me and go on with the call back*'. The event loop while the api are doing their job put in execution some other piece of code and resume the callback once the api has done.

You can find a good explanation here: [Understanding the Node.js Event Loop](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/)

Comment: You are welcome! Could you set it as the "answer" :) Thankyou.